# Bootstrap modal doesn't pop up when a node is clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

```
  'var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("a")
  .attr("class", "node")
       .attr("target", "_blank")
  .on("click",function(d){click(d)})
  .attr("data-toggle", "modal")
  .call(force.drag);'

 function click(d) 
 { 
 //node.attr("xlink:href",function(d){return d.url;})
 node.attr("data-toggle", "modal")
 node.attr("xlink:href","#myModal")

 }

'<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>'
```

I tried add myModal on the node attributes (mymodal is below code)
 And attach .on('click') to make it something happen after node is clicked

But in this way my page became only 'hide fade'but they don't show inside  pages like here :

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

they only make it fade and nothing happens, how can I fix this problem? :)

Comment: you should bind click event by yourself, if the clicky dom add after window ready (dynamic adding). Because bootstrap modal bind event when document loaded.

Comment: thanks for replying. I added                                                          .on("click",function(d){click(d)}) and define function as  function click(d)
  {
    // node.attr("xlink:href",function(d){return d.url;})
    node.attr("xlink:href","#myModal")
    node.attr("data-toggle", "modal") 
  }
but it still make it fade don't appear any other modal window

Comment: you have to trigger jQuery modal method for it. Like $("#myModal").modal('show').

Comment: Confirm you imported bootstrap javascript modules

Comment: Hey @JonghoKim! I know this was a looong time ago, but can you show how you approached this problem? I'm wanting to do something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class `hide` from the modal div:
`<div id="myModal" class="modal`<strike>`hide`</strike>`fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`